# Visual Studio Design View blank for Web Forms (including new projects)

Tags: visual-studio

Visual Studio unable to render Design View for any Web Forms page (including new projects).  When I select the Design view, it shows a blank page (see screenshot).
-   Error List is empty
-   Already rebooted
-   Not aware of any changes since the last time it worked
[Design view blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ipgw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed the issue:
 - Close Visual Studio
 - Go to the Windows Control Panel
 - Open "Programs and Features"
 - Right click on Visual Studio and select "Repair"

note: it might take a couple of hours to complete the repair